# Proper Use Of YouTube Url Regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I found this regex on stack overflow to get the youtube video id.

```
function ytVidId(youtubeurl) {
var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but I just don't understand how to actually use it.  How do I get this to affect my text input field named "youtubeurl" before it's prepared for the database?

Thanks a lot... Any help appreciated!

Comment: `url.match(p)[1]` should contain the ID. Log it to the console and see what the array contains. Then you can validate a value with the regex with `regex.test(str)`

Comment: I would suggest against using `RegExp.$1`.  It's deprecated.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the text from the textbox, perhaps with document.getelementbyid().value, then you could do (e.g if your textbox's id is #txt1 you can use this code:

```
function ytVidId(youtubeurl) {
var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
}

var ytURL = document.getelementbyid("txt1").value;
var ytID = ytVidID(ytURL);
```

now the variable ytID contains the youtube video ID and you can add it to the database how you want

Comment: Thank you! All the other variables that are sent to the database are done like - $_POST['youtubeurl'] in a prepared statement. Do you have any idea how I can set the new ID as a variable so I can use it in the same statement?

Comment: just swap youtubeurl for ytID, so long as you have that code present! like:
`var ytID = ytVidID(youtubeurl);`
`$_POST['ytID']`